# ewelink api not sending authorisation token in my linux server

Tags: node.js

```
const connection = new ewelink({
    email: '<your ewelink email>',
    password: '<your ewelink password>',
    region: '<your ewelink region>',
  });
```

Am not getting the authorisation token in my linux server while using same code in my local pc server am getting the authorisation token

Answer (score 0):

Use the .getCredentials() method

```
  const auth = await connection.getCredentials();
  console.log(auth);
  console.log('access token: ', auth.at);
  console.log('api key: ', auth.user.apikey);
  console.log('region: ', auth.region);
```

See: https://github.com/skydiver/ewelink-api/blob/master/docs/available-methods/getcredentials.md